# CSS - Replace URL text with an image

Tags: html, css

I want to replace the text of a url to an image. I am trying following:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="img">
    <a href="#">link</a>                    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img a{
    width: 96px; 
    height: 96px; 
    background: url("image.jpg"); 
    text-indent: -9999px; 
}
```

It would still show the text. I want the image instead of the text.

PS. I don't want to put the image in the html, ie.

```
<div class="img">
 <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" alt="image" /></a>                
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe post a jsfiddle of what you've done. My site has something just like this and it works fine.

Comment: what if you set a min-width and min-height in your CSS, and remove the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anchor tag is by definition an inline element and therefore will not accept height or width declarations.

To obtain your desired effect, use `display: inline-block;`. (won't work in IE<8 I believe)

```
.img a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 96px; 
    height: 96px; 
    background: url("image.jpg"); 
    text-indent: -9999px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-indent` applies to block level elements so just add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to the `.img a` CSS (this will also make the `width` and the `height` work).

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: hidden` with your current style definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact CSS trick that you should use to get this done.
But as per my knowledge I can make a suggestion.
You cannot have class name as "img" as it is already a HTMl tag.
If you write anything for it, that property will be considered for the `<img>` tag.